# Typescript prototype patch and jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, prototype, ts-jest

I have an issue with jest not recognizing merged interfaces correctly.

I have a decleration file from a @types/ library install with npm.
The implementation is implemented by the environment as a global in the production system and I have no access to it (think `window` as browser equivalent that is not defined in your code but exists non the less when js runs in a browser).

```
// @types/Foo/index.d.ts

interface Foo {
  A();
}
```

I then add more function to that interface using prototype

```
// src/monkeypatch.ts

declare global {
  interface Foo {
    B();
  }
}
Foo.prototype.B = function() {};
```

And use it in my code

```
// main.ts
import 'src/monkeypatch.ts'; // side effects import
```

```
// src/Bar.ts

class Bar {
  bar(foo: Foo) {
    foo.B();
  }
}
```

So far everything works as expected, my editor is happy, tsc is happy and everything runs just fine in production.

Now I want to set up unit tests and mock out the implementation for the unit test, I create an implementation.

```
// mocks/Foo.ts

class FooImpl implements Partial<Foo> {
  A() {};
}

export { FooIMpl as Foo };
```

And the test file

```
// src/Bar.spec.ts

import { Foo } from '../mocks/Foo';
(global as any).Foo = Foo;
import 'monkeypatch';  // patches A with additional methods

import { Bar } from 'Bar';

new Bar().bar(new Foo());
```

But I am getting the following error as if its not aware of the fact that the intefaces merged or that it was patched:

Argument of type 'FooImpl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo'.
Type 'FooImpl' is missing the following properties from type 'Foo': B.
ts(2345)

Changing the call site to `bar(new Foo() as any);` is a workaround and causes the test to pass but it smells horrible and I want this to work correctly, what am I missing?

The other issue is that I seem to have to use Partial to make the compiler happy, otherwise I get the following error:
Class 'FooImpl' incorrectly implements interface 'Foo'.
Type 'FooImpl' is missing the following properties from type 'Foo': B

Answer (score 0):

It seems patching *is recognized*, but your `FooImpl` is just defining `A(){}` and not `B(){}` as declared by yourself in `src/monkeypatch.ts`.

After the augmentation, Foo becomes

```
class Foo {
  A() {}
  B() {}
}
```

So to assign `FooImpl` to `Foo` you should implement both.

Comment: FooImpl is exported as Foo and set on global.Foo so monkeypatch.ts should be extending FooImpl and hence FooImpl is implementing B

Comment: Yes, and it will override the `FooImpl`, but when you *assign* the value to `global.Foo` you are providing, in TS eyes, full implementation, so you can't just say "I'll implement this later with monkeypatch.ts"

Comment: I guess I'll stick to my "as any" hack, declaring B in Foo.ts is not an option, I do not know what methods are added by monkeypatch.ts since I want to export the mocks as a library for others to use.

Comment: If I understood your case correctly, this would not matter, since the test is just, you know, a *test*, where you don't care about the monkeypatching. Am I wrong?

Comment: The monkeypatching is used by the code under test so I do care, think of code that adds size() to Array.prototype and then uses arr.size(), without the prototype the test will crash with arr.size is not defined. This is similar to my test environment doesn't have Array defined, only declared so I need to define Array and let other add to it via prototype if they want to